# Sed to replace multiline Java comment with another text

Tags: java, regex, sed

I have some java code:

```
/**
 * Some comment.
 */
void someFunction();

/**
 * Some comment.
 */
void anotherFunction();
```

How to write a single line `sed` to convert the above into

```
@Override
void someFunction();

@Override
void anotherFunction();
```

The best I could do is to just delete the comments with

```
sed '/\/\*\*/,/\*\// d'
```

and manually insert `@Override`.

EDIT: The method signature is not always void().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with a single pass of sed:

```
sed '/\/\*\*/,/\*\// {s/.*\*\/.*/@Override/p; d}'
```

The commands within the braces will only run for the lines that are a part of the comment, and the `s/.*\*\/.*/@Override/p` will only match the end of the comment and then print `@Override` as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you can also work with `awk`, this can make it:

```
$ awk '/\/\*/ {p=0; next} /\*\// {p=1; print "@Override"; next}p' file
@Override
void someFunction();

@Override
void anotherFunction();

@Override
char Bla();
```

For a given file

```
/**
 * Some comment.
 */
void someFunction();

/**
 * Some comment.
 */
void anotherFunction();

/**
 * Some comment.
 */
char Bla();
```

Comment: The method signature is not always void(), but the multiline comment is always used to lead a method. So, I think it's safer to target the comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to insert a new line after '*/'

```
sed '/\*\// a @Override' file
```

and then run your command -

```
sed '/\/\*\*/,/\*\// d' file
```

This way you can add @override for each method even if it doesn't start with void. But There should be comment section for each method.

Comment: Refer this useful link for sed - http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/01/sed-command-in-unix-examples.html